# Unable to start puppet

Tags: puppet

I would like to do puppet kick to a puppet agent. However, I am unable to start puppet as an agent with the following command on one server. No errors were given.

> puppet agent --no-client --listen

Are these the right command to run to start an agent listening?

```
Current version 
dpkg -l | egrep puppet
ii  facter                           1.7.2-1puppetlabs1           Ruby module for collecting simple facts about a host operating system
ii  hiera                            1.2.1-1puppetlabs1           A simple pluggable Hierarchical Database.
ii  puppet                           3.2.3-1puppetlabs1           Centralized configuration management - agent startup and compatibility scripts
ii  puppet-common                    3.2.3-1puppetlabs1           Centralized configuration management
ii  puppetlabs-release               1.0-7                        "Package to install Puppet Labs gpg key and apt repo"
ii  ruby-rgen                        0.6.5-1puppetlabs1           A framework supporting Model Driven Software Development (MDSD)
```

Comment: dont you have to `--waitforcert` the first time you run puppet agent?

Comment: please try puppet agent --test --noop and edit your question with details of errors or lack thereof.

Comment: `--waitforcert` is [enabled by default](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/man/agent.html). From the Puppet agent manpage: _This option only matters for daemons that do not yet have certificates and it is enabled by default, with a value of 120 (seconds)._

Answer (score 1):

Found out that you need to create /etc/puppet/auth.conf and populate it with the required entries to work.